# animateLayout on expanding component is not working - codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I went through the ratatouilles-restaurant code in blog. It was great. So I wanted to apply it in my app too but everything works fine except the smooth animation when the component is added. What went wrong in my code? Thankyou in advance.

```
protected void beforeTeamMemberTry(Form f) {
    screenWidth = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();

    Container mainContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    f.add(mainContainer);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Container memberContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        memberContainer.getAllStyles().setMargin(5, 5, 0, 0);
        mainContainer.add(memberContainer);

        Label icon = new Label(theme.getImage("loginBg.png").scaledWidth(screenWidth / 9));
        icon.setName("memberIcon");
        zeroPaddingMargin(icon);
        memberContainer.add(BorderLayout.WEST, icon);

        Container detailsContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        Container innerContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        detailsContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, innerContainer);
        innerContainer.setUIID("innerclkvjd");
        zeroPaddingMargin(innerContainer);
        innerContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
        innerContainer.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
        detailsContainer.setName("detailsContainer");
        zeroPaddingMargin(detailsContainer);
        detailsContainer.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
        memberContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, detailsContainer);
        Button email = new Button("bbeck@gmai.com");
        email.setName("memberEmail");
        zeroPaddingMargin(email);
        innerContainer.add(email);
        Label position = new Label("Senior member".toUpperCase());
        position.setName("memberPosition");
        zeroPaddingMargin(position);
        position.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xccccc0);
        position.getAllStyles().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
        innerContainer.add(position);

        Label emblemDown = new Label(">");
        emblemDown.setUIID("emblemDown");
        memberContainer.add(BorderLayout.EAST, emblemDown);

        Label emblemUp = new Label("<");
        emblemUp.setUIID("emblemUp");

        Container descriptionContainer = new Container();
        TextArea descriptionTextArea = new TextArea("slkdjfdlk dslkfdslkf jsdfksdl fksd flksd f;lsdkf sldkf sdlfk s;dl fksdl fksd flsd fkds");
        descriptionContainer.add(descriptionTextArea);
        descriptionTextArea.setName("memberDescription");
        zeroPaddingMargin(descriptionTextArea);
        descriptionTextArea.setEditable(false);
        descriptionTextArea.setGrowByContent(true);
        descriptionTextArea.setGrowLimit(5);

        memberContainer.setLeadComponent(email);

        email.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (emblemDown.getParent() != null) {
                memberContainer.add(BorderLayout.EAST, emblemUp);
                memberContainer.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, descriptionContainer);
                memberContainer.revalidate();
            } else {
                memberContainer.removeComponent(emblemUp);
                memberContainer.add(BorderLayout.EAST, emblemDown);
                memberContainer.removeComponent(descriptionContainer);
                memberContainer.revalidate();
            }
            memberContainer.getParent().animateLayout(300);
        });
    }
}
```

Details including phn no. (button) above in descriptionContainer but it cannot be clicked:

```
 Container descriptionContainer = new Container();
TextArea descriptionTextArea = new TextArea("slkdjfdlk dslkfdslkf jsdfksdl fksd flksd f;lsdkf sldkf sdlfk");
descriptionContainer.add(descriptionTextArea);
descriptionTextArea.setGrowByContent(true);
descriptionTextArea.setGrowLimit(2);

Container phnContainer = new Container();
descriptionContainer.add(phnContainer);
Label phnLabel = new Label("Phn: ");
Button phn = new Button("9802921323");
phnContainer.add(phnLabel);
phnContainer.add(phn);
phn.addActionListener(e->{ 
    System.out.println("bibek calls");
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have rearranged your code and change your animation code to `animateLayoutAndWait(300)`.

Also you shouldn't call both `revalidate()` and `animateLayout()`.

I also noticed that your animation was applied to the email button.

Finally, apply the animation to the right container, calling `memberContainer.getParent().animateLayout(300);` won't animate the emblems but the memberContainer placement.

```
protected void beforeTeamMemberTry(Form f) {
    screenWidth = Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth();

    Container mainContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    f.add(mainContainer);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Container memberContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        memberContainer.getAllStyles().setMargin(5, 5, 0, 0);

        Label icon = new Label(theme.getImage("loginBg.png").scaledWidth(screenWidth / 9));
        icon.setName("memberIcon");
        zeroPaddingMargin(icon);
        memberContainer.add(BorderLayout.WEST, icon);

        Container detailsContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        Container innerContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        detailsContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, innerContainer);
        innerContainer.setUIID("innerclkvjd");
        zeroPaddingMargin(innerContainer);
        innerContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
        innerContainer.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
        detailsContainer.setName("detailsContainer");
        zeroPaddingMargin(detailsContainer);
        detailsContainer.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
        memberContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, detailsContainer);
        Button email = new Button("bbeck@gmai.com");
        email.setName("memberEmail");
        zeroPaddingMargin(email);
        innerContainer.add(email);
        Label position = new Label("Senior member".toUpperCase());
        position.setName("memberPosition");
        zeroPaddingMargin(position);
        position.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xccccc0);
        position.getAllStyles().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
        innerContainer.add(position);

        Label emblemDown = new Label(">");
        emblemDown.setUIID("emblemDown");
        memberContainer.add(BorderLayout.EAST, emblemDown);

        Label emblemUp = new Label("<");
        emblemUp.setUIID("emblemUp");

        Container descriptionContainer = new Container();
        TextArea descriptionTextArea = new TextArea("slkdjfdlk dslkfdslkf jsdfksdl fksd flksd f;lsdkf sldkf sdlfk s;dl fksdl fksd flsd fkds");
        descriptionContainer.add(descriptionTextArea);
        descriptionTextArea.setName("memberDescription");
        zeroPaddingMargin(descriptionTextArea);
        descriptionTextArea.setEditable(false);
        descriptionTextArea.setGrowByContent(true);
        descriptionTextArea.setGrowLimit(5);

        memberContainer.setLeadComponent(email);

        email.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (emblemDown.getParent() != null) {
                memberContainer.add(BorderLayout.EAST, emblemUp);
                memberContainer.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, descriptionContainer);
            } else {
                memberContainer.removeComponent(emblemUp);
                memberContainer.add(BorderLayout.EAST, emblemDown);
                memberContainer.removeComponent(descriptionContainer);
            }
            memberContainer.animateLayoutAndWait(300);
        });
        mainContainer.add(memberContainer);
        mainContainer.animateLayoutAndWait(300);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks diamond. After I remove revalidate, it worked. But now I hav other issues, I need to display address, phn no. etc in place of detail and I cannot have action listener in phn to call directly from the app since the detail portion goes out if I click in it. Can we work it out smhow? updated the code above.Thankyou

Comment: Try removing the setLeadComponent().

Comment: Remove leadcomponent